# Anyone have experience using Pfsense SNORT to secure relays?

Tags: stake-pool

I've been exploring the wide array of content regarding relay and core node setup (prefer the manual approach).  I'd like to be as secure as possible and have been thinking about the use of tools / utilities such as SNORT on Pfsense.  Does anyone have experience using these utilities for their nodes?  If yes, what are the key lessons learned?

Thanks so much in advance for your support!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I’m surprised that I have not received feedback for this inquiry.  I will try posting this on the cardano community to see if the I get more feedback.  I would have expected pool security to have been a higher priority for most.